# how to prevent URL encoding a string in liquid templates?

Tags: templates, escaping, jekyll, liquid, url-encoding

I've got some strings i mash together and render on an image node like this:

```
 {% capture src %}   
 {{'https://example.com/'}} {{ padded }} {{'.jpg'}} 
 {% endcapture %}

 <td><img src="{{ src }}" />src</td>
```

but for some reason it's URL encoding the value of the `padded` variable (which in my case is '0004'. So the final output ends up looking like

```
<td><img src="https://example.com/%200004%20.jpg"/></td>
```

how do I ***not*** URL encode the `padded` variable?

Unfortunately, it does the same thing if I do

```
<img src="https://example.com/{{padded}}.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture starts at }, and ends at {. So when you capture

```
{{'https://example.com/'}} {{ padded }} {{'.jpg'}}
```

This gives `|https://example.com/ 0004 .jpg|`

And naturally the space within are url encoded.

Try `{{'https://example.com/'}}{{ padded }}{{'.jpg'}}`

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the behavior of `capture`. Capture takes the contents literally, as if they're rendered, so it included the spaces between `}}` and `{{` as literal spaces, which then got URL encoded.